# classification labels in headers and footers

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking

I'm trying to write Latex documents that will automatically satisfy government requirements for labeling certain classes of information:
 - Each paragraph starts with a label indicating its importance.
 - The header and footer of each page include a label indicating the
   most important paragraph on that page (even if it started on the
   previous page).

This is the closest I have come:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\parskip{.6\baselineskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\setlength\textheight{21\baselineskip}
\newcommand\pageimport{TRIVIAL}
\newcommand\paraimport{TRIVIAL}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}\chead{\leftmark}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\leftmark}\rfoot{\thepage}

\newcommand{\IMP}[1]{\renewcommand\paraimport{IMPORTANT}
  \renewcommand\pageimport{IMPORTANT}
  \markboth{\pageimport}{\paraimport}
  \afterpage{\renewcommand\pageimport{\protect\paraimport}\markboth{\protect\paraimport}{}}
\textcolor{red}{(I)  #1}\renewcommand\paraimport{TRIVIAL}}

\newcommand{\TRI}[1]{\renewcommand\paraimport{TRIVIAL}
  \markboth{\pageimport}{\paraimport}
  \afterpage{\renewcommand\pageimport{\protect\paraimport}\markboth{\protect\paraimport}{}}
(U)  #1\renewcommand\paraimport{TRIVIAL}}

\begin{document}
\immediate\typeout{a. pageimport = \pageimport\space  paraimport = \paraimport}
\TRI{\lipsum[1]}
\TRI{\lipsum[2]}
\TRI{\lipsum[3]}
\immediate\typeout{b. pageimport = \pageimport\space  paraimport = \paraimport}
\IMP{\lipsum[4]}
\immediate\typeout{c. pageimport = \pageimport\space  paraimport = \paraimport}
\TRI{\lipsum[5]}
\TRI{\lipsum[6]}
\TRI{\lipsum[7]}
\TRI{\lipsum[8]}
\immediate\typeout{d. pageimport = \pageimport\space  paraimport = \paraimport}
\IMP{\lipsum[9]}
\immediate\typeout{e. pageimport = \pageimport\space  paraimport = \paraimport}
\TRI{\lipsum[10]}
\TRI{\lipsum[11]}
\TRI{\lipsum[12]}
\end{document}
```

(I've changed the labels here to avoid causing needless alarm.  For
convenience, I have also set the "important" text in red.)  My idea is
to keep the "importance" of each paragraph in \paraimport.  That gets
reset at the end of each paragraph.  The header and footer get their
labels from \pageimport, which records the highest importance on the
current page.  At the end of each page, \pageimport gets reset to the
value of \paraimport.

This document has one "important" paragraph on page 2, and another
that starts on page 4 and ends on page 5.  All the paragraphs are
correctly labeled.  The first two pages have the right labels, but
pages 3 and 6 should be marked "trivial".  The tracing statements
before and after each "important" paragraph show that \pageimport is
not getting reset at the pagebreaks.

I suspect I'm moving something fragile, but rewriting the \afterpage
commands as

```
\afterpage{\renewcommand\pageimport{\protect\paraimport}\markboth{\protect\paraimport}{}}
```

makes no difference.

I've seen secret.sty, but it's attacking a different problem.  I have
not been able to adapt it for page marking.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think,`\afterpage` is not sufficient here. In my impression there must be check about the last 'state' (TRIVIAL/IMPORTANT)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

The key point is to reset left and right marks

```
\afterpage{%
\renewcommand\paraimport{TRIVIAL}%
\markboth{\paraimport}{\paraimport}
```

**Note** We need only one command `\paraimport`

**Update** the idea is to redefine `\parimport` and `\markboth` inside paragraphs i.e. just after (I).

**Updated MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\parskip{.6\baselineskip}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\setlength\textheight{21\baselineskip}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}\chead{\leftmark}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\leftmark}\rfoot{\thepage}

\newcommand\paraimport{TRIVIAL}
\markboth{\paraimport}{\paraimport}

\newcommand{\IMP}[1]{%
\textcolor{red}{(I)
\renewcommand\paraimport{IMPORTANT}%
\markboth{\paraimport}{\paraimport}%
 #1}%
\afterpage{%
\renewcommand\paraimport{TRIVIAL}%
\markboth{\paraimport}{\paraimport}}%
}

\newcommand{\TRI}[1]{(U)  #1}

\begin{document}
\TRI{\lipsum[1]}
\TRI{\lipsum[2]}
\TRI{\lipsum[3]}
\IMP{\lipsum[4]}
\TRI{\lipsum[5]}
\TRI{\lipsum[6]}
\TRI{\lipsum[7]}
\TRI{\lipsum[8]}
\IMP{\lipsum[9]}
\TRI{\lipsum[10]}
\TRI{\lipsum[11]}
\TRI{\lipsum[12]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - that does fix the MWE.  But I'd really like to know _why_ it works.

Comment: Unfortunately there is still a flaw.  My MWE included cases where the pagebreak occurred within a "trivial" paragraph or within an "important" one.  If I shorten the pages by one line using "\setlength\textheight{20\baselineskip}", then a pagebreaks occur just before an "important" paragraph, which triggers a bug: If a page starts with an "important" paragraph, then the _previous_ page is also marked "important".  Apparently by the time TeX decides to insert the pagebreak, \paraimport and \leftmark have already been set.  Any ideas how to handle that case?

Comment: I just found another similar topic "Content Aware Headers and Footers" at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97891/content-aware-headers-and-footers?rq=1.  Unfortunately the solution by @Eric has the same flaw: If a page starts with a higher classification than anything on the previous page, the previous page gets marked with the higher classification.

Comment: I update the answer fixing the bug. I will try to explain how later.

Comment: I think I see how your fix works.  By waiting until a few characters in the new paragraph have been scanned, we ensure that TeX has made its pagebreak decisions before we reset the headers and footers.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way @touhami, your method still works if only the "main mark" is set, using "\markboth{\paraimport}{}", After all, the header and footer only depend on \leftmark.

Comment: even more, you can use `\lhead{}\chead{\paraimport}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\paraimport}\rfoot{\thepage}` and no need to use `\markboth` at all. I just did not want to change you original code because i don't have the whole picture.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit old, but it still comes up high on a web search.  I was trying to adapt the solution for multiple importance levels and came across [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21522/61112) to check if a paragraph spans a page break.  My solution is to set a counter and increment the counter if a paragraph has a higher importance level than the current paragraph.  If the last paragraph on the page spans the page break, I set the page level on the next page to the current level and repeat the process.  What I came up with is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcounter{pagelevel}
\newcounter{currentlevel}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}

\newcounter{clscnt}
\makeatletter
% When we ship out the page, check if the paragraph spans the break.
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \ifnum\zref@extract{markingenv-begin-\theclscnt}{abspage}
            =\zref@extract{markingenv-end-\theclscnt}{abspage}
        \setcounter{pagelevel}{0}%
    \else
        \setcounter{pagelevel}{\thecurrentlevel}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\marking}[2]{%
    \stepcounter{clscnt}%
    \zlabel{markingenv-begin-\theclscnt}%
    (#1 --- \thepagelevel)
    \ifnum #1 > \thepagelevel%
        \setcounter{pagelevel}{#1}%
        \chead{Level \thepagelevel}%
    \fi%
    \setcounter{currentlevel}{#1}
    #2
    \zlabel{markingenv-end-\theclscnt}%
}

\newcommand{\VI}[1]{\marking{3}{(V) #1}}
\newcommand{\IMP}[1]{\marking{2}{(I) #1}}
\newcommand{\TRI}[1]{\marking{1}{(U) #1}}

\begin{document}
\TRI{\lipsum[1]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[2]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[3]\par}
\IMP{\lipsum[4]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[5]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[6]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[7]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[8]\par}
\IMP{\lipsum[9]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[10]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[11]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[12]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[13]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[14]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[15]\par}
\VI{\lipsum[16]\par}
\IMP{\lipsum[17]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[18]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[19]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[20]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[21]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[22]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[23]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[24]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[25]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[26]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[27]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[28]\par}
\TRI{\lipsum[29]\par}
\end{document}
```

I modified the example to explicitly show the page level and paragraph level.  Note that pages 3 and 4 correctly have the heading set to level 3 and the heading is reset to 1 on pages 5 and 6.

---

Edit: I've been tinkering with and extending this solution to make it into a [package](https://github.com/kprussing/secretx).

Comment: I've noticed this [logic is not perfect](https://github.com/kprussing/secretx/issues/2). In fact, it will occasionally fail to capture a paragraph that spans pages (and appears fails when a float is involved).

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the most complicated part of this problem is the case when a paragraph continues through a page break. Perhaps the easiest thing to do is to prevent paragraphs from doing so:

```
\widowpenalties 1 10000
\raggedbottom
```